# inputs.devices.all_devices Doesn't Find SNES Usb Gamepad

Tags: python, controller, usb, gamepad

I would like to use a SNES Usb Controller with a python game that I am making, however, I can't seem to detect the controller. The Windows Gamepad Controller Configure window finds the controller, and so does https://html5gamepad.com/, but python doesn't detect it. My computer detects it as "usb gamepad". That website also names it as usb gamepad (Vendor: 0810 Product: e501)

I have tried using the inputs library, but all it shows is my keyboard and mouse, nothing else.

Here's my code:

```
import inputs

print(inputs.devices.all_devices)
```

I would expect for my controller to print to the console, but it doesn't. All it prints is:

```
[inputs.Keyboard("/dev/input/by-id/usb-A_Nice_Keyboard-event-kbd"), inputs.Mouse("/dev/input/by-id/usb-A_Nice_Mouse_called_Arthur-event-mouse")]
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I managed to get it working. using [this website](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=controllers_and_graphics), I managed to detect controller input, but for some reason it still doesn't show up when I try to do `print inputs.devices.all_devices`.